# Unable to send more than 60 bytes TCP packets using traceroute or tcptraceroute

Tags: tcp, traceroute

```shellsession
[root@host33cn ~]# traceroute -M tcp -f 255 -m 255 -q 10 -w 1 -p 9101 10.11.1.6 1400
traceroute to 10.11.1.6 (10.11.1.6), 255 hops max, 60 byte packets
255  host05cn.zen.com (10.11.1.6)  0.112 ms  0.133 ms  0.070 ms  0.156 ms  0.091 ms  0.098 ms  0.072 ms  0.106 ms  0.113 ms  0.075 ms
[root@host33cn ~]#
```

Using above command trying to send 1400 bytes. Interface MTU is of 1500. But still it is sending default 60 byte packets for TCP.

Tried with 1000 and even less than 60 byte packets. Even though it is still taking 60 byte packets only.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

When using the tcp method (`-M tcp`),
by default, traceroute uses TCP SYN packets. 
From [traceroute(8)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/traceroute.8.html):

> **`tcp        -T`**
>
>   Well-known modern method, intended to bypass firewalls. 
>   Uses the constant destination port (default is 80, http).
>
> If  some  filters  are present in the network path, then most probably any "unlikely" udp ports (as for default method) or even icmp echoes (as for icmp) are filtered, and whole tracerouting will just stop at such a firewall. 
> To bypass a network filter, we have to use only allowed protocol/port combinations.  If we trace for some, say, mailserver, then more likely **`-T -p 25`** can reach it, even when **`-I`** can not.
>
> This method uses well-known "half-open technique", which prevents applications on the destination host from seeing our probes at all. 
> Normally, a tcp syn is sent. 
> For non-listened ports we receive tcp reset, and all is done. 
> For active listening ports we receive tcp syn+ack, but answer by tcp reset (instead of expected tcp ack), this way the remote tcp session is dropped even without the application ever taking notice.

As can be seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994131/send-tcp-syn-packet-with-payload),
TCP SYN packets are not supposed to contain a payload,
which is probably why traceroute ignores your packet length in this case.

traceroute could maybe be a little bit clearer and display a warning in that case (or refuse to run) to avoid confusing the user...

Note that the man page also mentions that the packet length can be ignored in some cases:

>   The optional
>   **`packet_len`**
>   `gth
>   is the total size of the probing packet
>   (default 60 bytes for IPv4 and 80 for IPv6). 
>   The specified size can be ignored in some situations
>   or increased up to a minimal value.

<sup>(The “ ` ” above is in the man page,
and appears to be a typo.)</sup>